# Prevent code duplication inside Python classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

Here is part of my code:

```
class classA(Something):

    CONFIG={
        "opt_a": "opt_b"
    }

    def construct(self):
         Some Unique Code
         .
         .
         .
         .
         Some Common Code

class classB(Something):

    CONFIG={
        "opt_a": "opt_b"
    }

    def construct(self):
         Some Unique Code
         .
         .
         .
         .
         Some Common Code
```

The `Some Common Code` part is over 200 lines and it is exactly the same in both `classA` and `classB`. I have to create 5 or more such classes. This will result in a lot of duplication.

Update:
The `Some Common Code` parts consists of a lot of loops and other functions that rely on data from `Some Unique Code`.

Update after Raphael's Solution:
There are some common variables in `classA` and `classB`. These variables are used both inside the "common code" as well as the "unique code". Moving them from one class to another creates variable `undefined` errors.

Here is my code after updates:

```
class Something(Else):
      
      CONFIG = {
          "alpha": "beta"
      }

      def setup(self):
            // Some Code
            return self

      def common_method(self):

            for i in texts:
                  // Manipulates Boxes

class classA(Something):

    CONFIG={
        "opt_a": "opt_b"
    }

    def construct(self):
         texts = []

         texts.append('Apple')
         .
         .
         .
         .
         self.common_method()

class classB(Something):

    CONFIG={
        "opt_a": "opt_b"
    }

    def construct(self):
         texts = []

         texts.append('Mango')
         .
         .
         .
         .
         self.common_method()
```

I am new to Python so I don't know how I can avoid this duplication. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is adding a method "common_method" to the Parent Class "Something" an option? You  can then call  "common_method" instead of writing "Some Common Code"

Comment: The "common code" mostly consists of `for` loops and other methods of the `Something` class. Will this be a problem?

Comment: not at all. I posted an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to @Raphael answer, we may focus on "construct" method and come up with such a structure:

```py
class Something:

    def common_method(self):
        """ """

    def construct(self):
        self.common_method()


class ClassA(Something):

    def construct(self):
        # A-specific code
         super().construct()


class ClassB(Something):

    def construct(self):
        # B-specific code
         super().construct()
```

, but it is hard to say what will be better without more details.

UPDATE:
If you need to manipulate with common variables alongside different methods, then you need to set them as `object attributes` (or `class attributes`).

In python there is a special method - `__init__` that is used to construct an object.

Here is an example for your case:

```py
class Something(Else):

    def __init__(self):
        self.texts = []
        
    CONFIG = {
        "alpha": "beta"
    }

    def setup(self):
        # Some Code
        return self

    def common_method(self):

        # Manipulates Boxes
        for i in self.texts:
            pass


class classA(Something):

    CONFIG={
        "opt_a": "opt_b"
    }

    def construct(self):
        self.texts.append('Apple')
        self.common_method()


class classB(Something):

    CONFIG={
        "opt_a": "opt_b"
    }

    def construct(self):
        self.texts.append('Mango')
        self.common_method()
```

Comment: Thanks @hidden. :) I have added an update to the question based on Raphael's answer. Will your method solve the `undefined` variable error?

Comment: @RealNoob, both suggested structures should work for you. Show us a simplified example of your code so we could understand where do you do mistakes.

Comment: I will try to create a simplified version and post it in the question details. :)

Comment: Hi @hidden, could you please take a look at the code now? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @hidden. I am getting an `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'window_config'` error with the above code.

Comment: `Else` is child of yet another class which also uses `__init()__`. Could this create any errors?

Comment: @RealNoob, I think you should create a new question and describe your problem. But first, spend some time reading some tutorials about __init__ method and python classes in general.

Comment: Thanks @hidden. :) I will read more about `init`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply outsource "common code" to a common method of the parent class

Note: if CONFIG is also identical for your sub classes you can outsource this also to the parent class

```
class Something:

    def common_method(self):
        pass  # common stuff
    

class ClassA(Something):

    CONFIG={
        "opt_a": "opt_b"
    }

    def construct(self):
         self.common_method()
         ...
         self.common_method()


class ClassB(Something):

    CONFIG={
        "opt_a": "opt_b"
    }

    def construct(self):
         self.common_method()
         ...
         self.common_method()
```

Update:
The error in your update comes from the variable "texts" which is not defined within the common method.
One way to solve this is to make texts an instance variable.

```
class ParentClass:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.texts = []
    
    def common_method(self):
        for text in self.texts:
            print(text)

class classA(ParentClass):

    def construct(self):
        self.texts.append('Apple')
        ...
        self.common_method()
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael. I am getting errors about  undefined vaiables when I move variables from parent class to child or child to parent

Comment: @RealNoob its hard to tell what is going wrong without an example

Comment: Hi @Raphael, could you please take a look at the code now? Thanks.